# Python - Multithreading - Does Lock have to be global?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I am beginner of multithreading in python.
I want to use a Lock in threads. Does it have to be declared global in the thread?
My code looks like this:

```
i = 0
lock = threading.RLock()
def do_work():
  global i
  # global lock ?????????????
  while i < len(my_list):
    lock.acquire()
    my_i = i
    i += 1
    lock.release()
    my_list[my_i].some_works()

workers = [threading.Thread(target=do_work) for _ in range(8)]
for worker in workers:
  worker.start()
```

Comment: Are you asking if you have to use the `global` keyword or if the scope of your `lock` variable is correct?

Comment: I am asking what is the correct usage.

Comment: Common practice is to pass the lock as an argument to `do_work`. So `do_work` becomes `do_work(lock)`, and you create the thread with `threading.Thread(target=do_work, args=(lock,))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not have to be global. You can create it in a function and then pass it to your threads as an argument like so:

```
i = 0

def do_work(lock):
    global i

    while i < len(my_list):
        with lock: # cleaner way to .acquire() and .release()
            my_i = i
            i += 1
         my_list[my_i].some_works()

def main():
    lock = threading.RLock()

    workers = [threading.Thread(target=do_work, args=lock,) for _ in range(8)]
    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()

main()
```

Comment: I am not into this, but it looks like Mark Dickinson's comment that helped me when I posted the question, so I accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, no `global` does not have to be used for the thread to know what the lock variable is. [Here is more information on scope in Python](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Variables_and_Scope.html#more-about-scope-crossing-boundaries)

Unfortunately, the answer to "the correct usage" depends on your application/situation. There is nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing as long as your lock is actually global to your application. If your lock is not global to your application or if you want to break your application apart, you may do so by creating your own thread objects. [Here is a great tutorial on using threads/locks.](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Lock_Objects_Acquire_Release.php)

Good Luck!